# Quantile Regression -- special considerations for time series?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, quantile-regression, hydrology

I'm working on analyzing some hydrological time series/discharge data (for context, I don't have that extensive of a background in statistics or with time series). Essentially, the data is daily discharge measurements from the last ~80 years or so, quite an extensive record. I know from reading various sources that quantile regression makes no assumption of the distribution of the data like OLS. It is pretty ideal for hydrological data which tends to be heavily skewed right and with many outliers. Previous people in my group have used the `rq()` function in the `quantreg` package in R to perform linear quantile regressions on the dataset, usually on the 5th, 25th, 50th, 75th, and 95th quantiles.

However, I am struggling to find information that makes sense to me on whether autocorrelation in time series data impacts quantile regression results. Additionally, each observation would not be independent in the case of time series. Does anyone know how quantile regression is impacted by autocorrelation, and can explain it to me in very basic terms? Is performing a quantile regression on the data in this manner something that makes sense/ are the assumptions being met? Or perhaps are there better trend analysis options I should be considering, that are more apt for time series?